# AddThis Counts vs Facebook Counts

Tags: facebook, addthis, like

Recently I changed [Facebook Like buttons](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) on several of my sites for [AddThis counting buttons](http://www.addthis.com/) which include the Facebook count (or so I assume that is what the number in the box next to 'f like' is).

From a code point-of-view this is simpler and gives also counts and sharing buttons for other services. **However, the counts were mostly reset to 0 or at least to a much lower number than before.**

**Why the discrepancy? What could the two things be counting differently?**

Comment: Have you added this line to your pages' HTML tag: <html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

Comment: No... What does that do? It's not in the instructions (See link in the question).

Comment: Nothing helps so far... Is there any way to diagnose this?

Comment: WHat were the offending elements? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug. I discovered that some of the AddThis customization options cause the FB totals not to be added correctly. I have stopped using the offending elements.

Answer (score 1):

The page http://www.addthis.com/social-plugins/facebook-like-button states a different namespace to that mentioned above.  It should be:

`<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">`

I've just tried it and it works fine, my counter is back.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the HTML tag at the top of each of your files:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

This comes from this page: http://www.addthis.com/features/facebook-like-button

Comment: No effect... All counters remain the same.

Comment: Other people have had the same problem: http://www.addthis.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=32187&p=120219&hilit=facebook+counts&sid=86fe3cee4b879e018150aa5ae62c065d#p120219 Do you want to check to see if you haven't made the same mistakes.